# "failed building wheel for twisted" in ubuntu

Tags: python, twisted, python-wheel

When I run "pip install twisted" it shows ["failed building wheel for twisted"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXV2v.png)  How can I install "twisted" outside the virtualenv ? I'm using ubuntu 17.04 and Wheel version 0.30.0

Answer (score 2):

I has simular issues, installing gcc solved it.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this,** it worked for me.

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev python-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`

`pip install --verbose twisted`

`pip install -U Channels`

Comment: all I needed was `sudo apt install python3-dev`

Answer (score 1):

Your error says `Permission Denied` meaning you need to run the command using `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install twisted
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.switch to the admin terminal with:

```
sudo -H gnome-terminal
```

then retry `pip install twisted`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the error log, the "Permission denied" error is thrown.

You may try `pip install --user twisted`(recommended) or `sudo pip install twisted` instead.